# Count the number of VBA recipients in the TO field

Tags: vba, count, outlook

Is there a faster method to count the number of VBA recipients in the TO field?

Please refer to the following pseudo code.

```
Dim myRecipients as Outlook.recipients
Dim Recip as Outlook.recipient

Dim olToCount as Long
    olToCount = 0
For Each Recip In myRecipients
    If Recip.Type = olTo Then
        olToCount = olToCount + 1
    End if
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also read the To property and count the number of ";" characters, but it is locale specific. What you have is the preferable way; is there a problem with it?